# Haskell traverse and filter through a list while lifting results

Tags: haskell, monads, either, traversable

Say I have code where I want to do the following:

1. Input: a list of strings `[String]`
2. Operation (`checkSat` and `checkResult`)

   - Obtains a boolean from an input string.
3. Output:

   - If everything in the input is parseable into a boolean, only return those that resulted in "unsat".
   - If at least one of them has an error, return an error.

```hs
data Err = Err String deriving (Show)

-- Detail omitted for this example
checkSat :: String -> Either Err String
checkSat = Right . id

checkResult :: String -> Either Err Bool
checkResult "sat"    = Right True
checkResult "unsat"  = Right False
checkResult err      = Left $ Err err

onlyUnsat :: [String] -> Either Err [String]
onlyUnsat xs = filter (traverse notSat xs) xs
  where notSat x  = fmap not $ checkSat x >>= checkResult
        onlyUnsat = filter (traverse notSat xs) xs
```

The code above doesn't quite work. What's the right way to write `onlyUnsat` with the correct typing?

Comment: untested, but `fmap (filter not) . traverse (checkSat >=> checkResult)`?

Comment: [`Control.Monad.filterM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM) looks useful for this, I think.

Comment: `filterM (checkSat >=> fmap not . checkResult)` - if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```hs
onlyUnsat :: [String] -> Either Err [String]
onlyUnsat = traverse checkSat >=> filterM (fmap not . checkResult)

  where

  filterM :: Applicative m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
  filterM p = fmap (map fst . filter snd) . traverse (\x -> withFst x <$> p x)
    where withFst x = \y -> (x, y)

  (>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
  f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g
```

Note that both `filterM` and `>=>` can be imported from `Control.Monad`. I've redefined them here for the sake of clarity :-)

The basic idea is to split the operation into two stages: (1) apply `checkSat` on every item in the list; and (2) filter every item in the list. The first stage is given by `traverse checkSat`, which has type `[String] -> Either Err [String]`. The second stage is given by `filterM (fmap not . checkResult)`, which also has type `[String] -> Either Err String`. We then use `>=>` to chain these two computations together into one of the same type.